# Nested If statement 3 conditions and 1 definitive

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've had a look around on a few questions asked already regarding nested if statements and cant seem to get the answers suggested to fit my problem.

I am trying to get a result based on 3 conditions but one of the conditions is a definitive, the conditions are:

- `<9000 * 42.25%`
- `=9011 * 106.91%`
- `>9000 but not 9011 * 89.67%`

I have tried writing this multiple ways, the closest Ive managed to get to a result is:

```
=IF(K2<9000,K2*0.4225,IF(K2=9011,K2*38967,K2*1.0691))
```

The only problem with this is that it calculates anything under 9000 and thats it.

If anyone could offer any help that would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you have the numbers reversed in the second IF and we can remove the K2 to avoid multiple typing:

```
=IF(K2<9000,0.4225,IF(K2=9011,1.0691,0.8967)) * K2
```

Answer (score 1):

2 nested `IFs()` is the correct way to do it. You have reversed the 2. and the 3. conditions a bit:

`=IF(K2<9000,K2*0.4225,IF(K2=9011,K2*1.0691,K2*0.8967))`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much